# Object always active in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I am making my first 3D Unity game and I've encountered an issue where my sniper rifle game object is always active and I have no idea why. (I have multiple weapons and switch between them via a weapon switcher using the mouse wheel/number keys as input) it is active even when other weapons are active causing them to clip through each other during gameplay.I have confirmed that it is not my code causing the issue. I think it might be something to do with my animations? I really don't know. If you need more images or code snippets leave a comment or answer.

[Animator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6G0U.png)

Comment: Yes please, we would like to see the details of the problem before giving any advice blindly.

Comment: Animations could indeed be activating/deactivating game objects.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a weapon switcher game object which all of my guns are under. I have a system where my scrollwheel as well as the number keys can switch between the weapons, when a new one is set to active the previous one is set to inactive. there shouldnt be a way for two weapons to be active at the same time but the sniper rifle does, fully working with shooting and everything on both. they just clip into eachother in the players hand